# Always summoning brown coated baby villagers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

To summon a baby villager, I run

```
/summon villager ~1 ~ ~1 {Age:-6000}
```

It seems like I am getting brown coated villagers every time.

Fletcher, farmers, fishermen and shepherds.

Is that command line wrong or is there a bug?

## edit

It seems like I get all types if I summon adult villagers.

Comment: Which version do you play in?

Comment: Ok, snapshot apparently, found the cause.

Answer (score 2):

This is the bug [MC-140961](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-140961): "Villager babies have no profession"

When you spawn baby villagers, the command feedback actually tells you "Summoned new Nitwit", "Summoned new Cartographer" and so on, but they all turn out to have brown coats. When they grow up, they get their proper coats, but if they randomly happen to keep a brown coat, you cannot trade with them.

This apparently means that there can be no new farmers, fishermen, shepherds or fletchers (that can trade) apart from the ones generating with villages. This is a pretty big problem for Skyblock-type maps, since it makes optaining some items considerably harder, for example cookies would now require a wandering trader.

<s>Since this is a pretty bad bug, I invite everyone reading this to vote for it on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-140961), so that it gets more attention from the developers and hopefully gets fixed before 1.14.0.</s>

Update: With the new way of villagers acquiring their profession, I'm not sure anymore if this is intended. The command feedback is definitely weird, but since they can now change professions and children don't have any, the majority of this behaviour might be intended.

Comment: But I get command feedbacks like "Summoned new shepherd". They are not professionless, but their professions are only a subset of all professions. Those with brown coats.

Comment: As I said, they have different professions, they just all look the same as babies. And when they become adults, they show their professions, but brown-coats don't trade.

Comment: If I use the summon command with age -6000, I will never get a feedback message like "Summoned new Librarian" but for instance "Summoned new Shepherd". They do not seem to have their coats or professions changed when they grow up.

Comment: That's weird, it's different from how it behaves for you. Which version are you in?

Comment: 1.13.2. It seems like `Profession` defaults to 0 if I have specified `Age` (but `Career` is random). If I run the command without `Age` both are chosen randomly.

Comment: Right, in 1.13.2 they all stay brown-coats and have trades. Still a bug, but a different one. There's not really a point in linking to a bug report, since it's already "fixed" (changed) in the snapshots.

Comment: If I specify `Profession:1`, I will get a white coated villager.